# Windows 2008 IIS Fast CGI PHP or Windows 2008 with ubuntu guest w/LAMP stack?

Tags: windows-server-2008, ubuntu, virtual-machines

I have a server that I have co-located in a datacenter. It is a Quad Xeon (5130) with 8GB of RAM.  I have a few usb and serial port devices (peripherals) attached to it which require Windows to run.

I would like to add web hosting a (production) website onto this server's workload.  The website is runs on a LAMP stack.  After much reading, it seems that hypervisors and VM installs don't seem to work with peripherals (physical serial ports etc). Please correct me if I'm wrong.

So I was thinking about running Windows 2008 server x64bit and installing Vbox 4.0 (Ubuntu guest )on it to handle the production LAMP stack.  I was also thinking about running the LAMP stack on IIS 7.0 w/FASTCGI.  Which option do you think is better?  Are there other options that I'm not considering?

Syirrus

Answer (score 0):

If you are stuck in a lamp stack you are probably better off using a virtualization solution. Performancewise the fastcgi solution would be faster but more dificult to administer. I would however encourage you to [migrate the site to an IIS solution](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/719/migrate-to-a-windows-based-platform/) since you already have a windows system, if performance is a concern.

Comment: I think I will investigate running IIS for my web server. Performance and realiablty being of great importance whether its MS or Linux.  Thank you very much for your suggestions.  Is there anyone else that has anything to add?